# Horizontal Launch Trajectory movement

Tags: android, game-physics, physics

i'm kinda stuck here with my thoughts..I have a picture of what i want accomplish. I think its the best way to explain.

[image]

The red points are the starting positions. I want all of them to hit the same Spots on the ground, while right from the start moving in a parabola. Sadly im not that great of a math geek to get this working. It is important that the paths are always staying the same. I dont know if i could accomplish this with simple physics (gravity) Box2D maybe.
Thanks for any tip!

EDIT: i maybe thought that this could be accomplished by giving the objects the same y speed, but different x speeds. But this would be kinda hard coded..still looking for some practical answers :/

---

I`ve tried some math formulas, but i cant get this to work the way i want it :/.

Used those:

x = v*t*cos(alpha)
y = (v*t*sin(alpha))-(0.5*g*t^2)

Comment: by the by, your explanation also means that the speed of the balls would have to be faster the lower they are.

Comment: no, i want them to take longer to get to those spots, depending on the  starting y position. and i also want them to return to this height, when they hit the ground, but in a curved path.. My image isnt that great, because for the most upper ball, the path is only half is high as it should be.

Comment: ok, so the ball always bounces back up to its original height? and the higher the ball is, the longer the time to get back down?

Comment: Right, they all move at the same speed, with the same mass, they just need to hit the same spots at the ground, but not at the same time

Comment: and there is no atmosphere *(since they always return to the same height)*, and they are subject to different amounts of gravity *(since they can travel different amounts of total air distance at the same speed)* ;)

Comment: Exactly, thats my problem. They are not affected by gravity or friction (at least not all the same way). I just want them to move these paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if im allowed to answer my own question..

I just want to let you know a solution i m using now. Its not optimal, but i guess it works:

I've implemented a Time.class to save my deltaTime. In my Enemy class i got this for the movement:

```
    distance = 100;
    vY = targetTime*gravity*0.5f;
    vX = distance / targetTime;
```

and in the update method:

```
      x += vX * Time.deltaTime;
      y -= vY * Time.deltaTime;

      vY -= gravity;
      if(y >= 280)
        vY = -vY;
```

So after hitting the ground i just turn the y-velocity around. This especially works in my case, because the gravity kicks back in after some time and gets the enemy back to the ground.
Its still hard coded but i dont know better than do this.

Answer (score 0):

obviously, you're not accounting for your vector linear line of matter. It is the vector linear parallel in which will provide your points of pinpointing the pin you want pinned.
i.e., your ups to the pin point of a good hard fall is the desired result you seek. Must have repetitive falls and can only do so when accounting for vector linear parallel.